# Is it possible in Rails3, to have a multipart form => true & use remote => true

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using the following form tag for @jobs which have job_photos included.

```
<% form_for @jobs, :html => { :multipart => true }, :remote => true do |f| %>
```

The form works fine non-remote, but if I add the remote = > true, the form submits, returns create.js but doesn't save anything to the DB or error?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The thing is that you cannot post a multipart form via AJAX. This is not a rails' limitation. In order to circumvent this, you need to use an iframe technique (which can be easier with [responds_to_parent](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/responds_to_parent) plugin) or use a technology like Flash or Silverlight.

Comment: The reason why AJAX and file-uploading don't rhyme is that Javascript does not have access to your filesystem, and therefore can't construct the request from the file. In a multipart form, the browser does have access to your filesystem and therefore is able to make a POST request containing the file.

Comment: That sucks.  I wanted to do that.  I feel like I wasted the last 3 hours writing this to realize it wasn't going to work :p

Comment: Do check the remotipart gem as in Musaffa's answer.  Works like a charm, and is a two line addition.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [Remotipart](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) gem for file uploads with `remote` => `true`.