# error 406, remote: true Ajax form is still causing a redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

This has had me stumped all day.

My app provides for the upload of documents, once uploaded it runs create.js.erb and adds the new record to the page.

My HTML looks like this,

```
<div id="doc_upload">
  <%= form_for Document.new, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.file_field :file, multiple: true, name: "document[file]" %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :plot_id %>
  <%= f.submit 'upload' %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I have a create.js.erb file in the documents directory. I am presently using JQuery file upload and the drag and drop file upload causes no issues. However when I use this form to manually select a file and upload I get:

- a 406 HTTP error
- the page redirects to /documents
- when i go back, the file has been successfully uploaded and saved.

The headers are as follows.

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/documents
Request Method:POST
Status Code:406 Not Acceptable
Request Headersview source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8}
```

my controller is:

```
def create
  @document = Document.create(params[:document])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

As I said this really has me scratching my head, as the Ajax request doesnt seem to be firing. Does this mean that it may be something to do with the unobtrusive JS no picking up the remote true data type.  That is the only reason that I can think of the redirection.

If so how I confirm and fix this?

Any help would be great.

Ross

Comment: You can't use ajax to post multipart forms, so the form is likely just posting normally, causing the 406 response because your controller only responds to js requests.  As to why it's actually uploading the file somehow, that's more of a mystery.

Comment: that would be my jquery file upload... ummmn this is really helpful, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add [:multipart => true](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for#103-Multipart-form) if you have file upload in your form.

but [you cannot post a multipart form via AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009252/is-it-possible-in-rails3-to-have-a-multipart-form-true-use-remote-true/4009466#4009466)