# Sending a form with remote true in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form for updating an image with

```
<%= form_for current_user, url: update_image_user_path(current_user), method: :post, html: {multipart: :true, remote: true},  :authenticity_token => true do |f| %>
```

the action has

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.js
        format.html
    end
```

but I am getting the following error

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template users/update_image, application/update_image with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}.
```

I don't have a update_image.html.erb template, but from the error I learn that the request isn't sent as js format

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8):

There are several things you should know.

1. Ajax uses something called an xmlhttprequest to send your data. Unfortunately, xmlhttprequests cannot post files.  Remotipart may work, but there is far much more documentation, plus a rails cast video, on jqueryfileupload.  It is used by many sites (a lot that don't even use rails).  I would suggest using the jqueryfileupload-rails gem along with the rails cast:

   A.  https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails

   B.  http://railscasts.com/episodes/381-jquery-file-upload
2. remote: true is not an html attribute.  Change your code tho:

   ```
   <%= form_for current_user, url: update_image_user_path(current_user), 
       method: :post, html: {multipart: :true}, remote: true,  
       :authenticity_token => true do |f| %>
   ```

The most important part of the error you are encountering is this:

```
:formats=>[:html]
```

That should say:

```
:formats=>[:js]
```

With remote:true in the right place now, the error should go away.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Your second approach works fine for me.
Thanks a lot @Philip7899

Answer (score 5):

rails remote true will not work for image upload. You can not upload image with ajax using only remote true. You need jquery.form.js file to user ajaxForm. For this include

```
    <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

and bind form

```
     $("#formid").ajaxForm()
```

Alternatively you can use jqueryfileupload-rails gem

https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails

Answer (score 2):

How about `html: {multipart: :true}, remote: true` instead of `html: {multipart: :true, remote: true}`?

Comment: I'm not sure. But maybe the error is caused by a ajax limitation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009252/is-it-possible-in-rails3-to-have-a-multipart-form-true-use-remote-true