# controller does not respond to Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I would like to use Ajax to add a micropost to my home page without redirect as soon as it is created. I added `remote: true` in the form:

```
<%= form_for(@micropost, html: { multipart: true }, remote: true) do |f| %>
```

and edited the create action of the microposts controller as follows:

```
def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
    microposts_number = current_user.microposts.where("created_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day).count
    if microposts_number < 10
        if @micropost.save
            respond_to do |format|
                format.html do
                    flash[:success] = "Micropost created!"
                    redirect_to root_url
                end
                format.js
            end
        else
            @feed_items = []
            flash[:danger] = @micropost.errors.full_messages.join(', ')      
            render 'static_pages/home'
        end
    else
        flash[:danger] = "You have exceeded your daily share of microposts (10)."
        redirect_to root_url
    end
end
```

The microposts are shown in the home page as orded list of items, where `@feed_items` is a collection of microposts for `current_user`, thus belonging to Micropost:

```
<% if @feed_items.any? %>
  <ol class="microposts">
    <%= render @feed_items %>
  </ol>
  <%= will_paginate @feed_items %>
<% end %>
```

Therefore I created `app/views/microposts/create.js.erb`, using jQuery to select `ol.microposts` and function `prepend()` to add the newly created micropost to the page:

```
$("ol.microposts").prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: @micropost) %>');
```

The partial `_micropost.html.erb`, used to build the `li` elements inside `ol.microposts` is (simplified) below:

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, size: 50), micropost.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %></span>
  <span class="content">
    <%= micropost.content %>
    <%= image_tag micropost.picture.url if micropost.picture? %>
  </span>
</li>
```

However the Micropost controller does not respond to the Ajax request but redirect to `root_url`, responding only to html (output from cloud9 server):

```
Started POST "/microposts" for 82.56.61.198 at 2017-07-14 09:44:55 +0000
Cannot render console from 82.56.61.198! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by MicropostsController#create as HTML
...

Started GET "/" for 82.56.61.198 at 2017-07-14 08:51:42 +0000
Cannot render console from 82.56.61.198! Allowed networks: 127.0.0.1, ::1, 127.0.0.0/127.255.255.255
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML
```

I do not understand why the create action of the Micropost controller does not respond to js format. I tried to clone partial `_micropost.html.erb` and use the instance variable `@micropost` instead of the variable `micropost` of the iteration, but it did not work. There are no errors in the server log.

Comment: first of all you should respond on every if/else-path to js as well.

Comment: What does the log says when you submit? I believe the request format is `HTML`

Comment: I copied and pasted the server log at the end of my original message. It started to `get /` after about 5 seconds of initial waiting, which is what the  `respond_to html` says to do.

Comment: No, not that. I need a log that gets printed as soon as you submit the form

Comment: I updated my original message: `Processing by MicropostsController#create as HTML`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Processing by MicropostsController#create as HTML

It is due to the **limitation** of `AJAX`. From the [*Reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21679310/sending-a-form-with-remote-true-in-rails-4)

> Ajax uses something called an `xmlhttprequest` to send your data.
>   Unfortunately, xmlhttprequests **cannot** post files

That said, you cannot post files via AJAX. You may need some help with [*Remotipart*](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart) or [*Jquery-File-Upload*](https://github.com/tors/jquery-fileupload-rails)

Answer (score 1):

You only told the action to `respond_to` with `format.js` in your successful save path. You'll need to add a `respond_to` block with whatever you want to do for your `js` everywhere you `render` or `redirect_to`

Comment: I would like to respond to `js` only `if @micropost.save` and to `html` in all other cases.