# Rendering partial in Rails with .js.erb file (remote true trigger) not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

I'm attempting to render a partial when a user changes their profile avatar (as opposed to the page reloading). The problem is that the .js.erb file doesn't seem to be getting triggered at all (my console log messages aren't printing). I don't seem to be getting any errors as it simply redirects the page to the root.

In my server log (as seen below), there is a token authenticity error, but even when I disable the authentication and the error disappears, the redirect still happens and the .js.erb is essentially ignored.

```
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9ae101c3f8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20140716-9847-v0ray3>, @original_filename="creator.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"creator.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Upload Avatar", "id"=>"2"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 2 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "2"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "avatar" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "users"."id" = 2  [["avatar", "creator.jpg"], ["updated_at", Wed, 16 Jul 2014 14:41:14 UTC +00:00]]
   (160.8ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
```

**.js.erb file**

```
$(".avatar-container").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'profile/avatarContainer')) %>");
```

**User Controller**

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @user.update_attributes(params.require(:user).permit!)
          format.js
          format.html{
            redirect_to root_path
          }      
        else
          format.js
          format.html{redirect_to root_path}
        end
    end
  end
```

**Partial**:

```
-if current_user.avatar.url != "/assets/userProfile_dashboard.png"
  .avatar-large
    =image_tag current_user.avatar.url
    = simple_form_for(current_user, html: {:multipart => true }, remote: true) do |f|
      = f.file_field :avatar, style:"margin-top:-258px;", id: "profile-avatar"
      = f.button :submit, "Upload Avatar", :class => "buttonRoundedCornersGreen ", style: "width:130px;margin-top:20px;", id: "avatar-submit"
-else
  .no-avatar 
    = simple_form_for(current_user, html: {:multipart => true }, remote: true) do |f|
      = f.file_field :avatar, id: "profile-avatar"
```

**EDIT**:
After much searching, it appears that having a multipart true for file uploads and remote true were [creating a conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009252/is-it-possible-in-rails3-to-have-a-multipart-form-true-use-remote-true). I was able to resolve this by installing the [Remotipart gem](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart).

Comment: Have you made sure jquery-rails is in gemfile? Just making sure jquery-ujs library is loaded.

Comment: Yes, jquery-rails is in there. Does my .js.erb file need to be required anywhere?

Comment: no you dont require the js.erb file.   When inspecting the html for the page with the form on it, does the form have the data-remote="true" tag like <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users" data-remote="true" method="put">

Comment: Yes, it looks like this: <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/2" class="simple_form edit_user" data-remote="true" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_user_2" method="post" novalidate="novalidate">

Comment: ok in your layout file you are requiring application.js?  If so, does application js contain require jquery and require jquery_ujs

Comment: Yes, I'm requiring application.js and it is requiring both of those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57427/discussion-between-emcanes-and-kyle).

Comment: What happens if you pass format.js and empty hash. That is: format.js {}

Comment: You mean how it's defined in the controller? It currently is format.js{}. Also, I'm able to remove the js.erb file completely and I don't receive any missing template errors.

Comment: Ok, I resolved the issue by installing the Remotipart gem. Apparently, I'm not able to post a multipart form with remote true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much searching, it appears that having a multipart true for file uploads and remote true were [creating a conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009252/is-it-possible-in-rails3-to-have-a-multipart-form-true-use-remote-true). I was able to resolve this by installing the [Remotipart gem](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart).